# Best desktop browser to test Sencha Touch application?

Tags: sencha-touch

For testing without an iPhone/Android phone, which desktop browser works best with Sencha Touch? I tried Chrome and Safari, which work fairly well, but both seem to have little issues.
Firefox and IE apparently don't work at all with Sencha Touch. Is there a secret weapon, like a port of a mobile browser, available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the iPhone/iPad hardware simulator on a mac, or the Android simulator if you're on Windows. Desktop browsers will get you there - particularly desktop safari -- although there are enough differences that you should really use one of the simulators

Comment: I agree with this, but with two caveats; the simulators only simulate software, not the hardware; so performance is likely to be better on the simulator than on the actual device. I've also come across some CSS differences when testing between simulated and actual devices. Chrome & Safari both make good in-between solutions, particularly for DOM exploration and their JavaScript consoles & logging. But **always test on an actual device**, can't stress it enough.

Answer (score 5):

There's a Chrome extension called Ripple that's pretty good, but most things can be tested quite productively in Chrome. Set `Ext.is.Phone = true;` at the beginning of your script when you need to test the phone UI.

Answer (score 3):

A direct link to one ipad simulator online is: http://ipadpeek.com/

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, Google Chrome is my favorite browser. When I'm done developing a section of the app I do test it on my real device, an HTC desire (Android). As expected, the real device is WAY slower than desktop browser, specially notable on animations, e.g sliding tabs and carousels.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Google chrome is the best browser till date.... and its an ideal browser for sencha touch applications to run, since it contains webkit..

Also you can use Titanium ([you can download it here](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/download/)) which has iphone/iPad simulater built in but for that you need a Mac and you also have to download ios sdk.
Working on these simulators is an awesome experience.